# Anyone can tell me what's wrong with this pseudo code?

Tags: java, junit

I am not familiar with JUnit so not sure if that's the problem of `assertTrue(b_exception);`, because if I put an `System.out.println("something");` there, it would print out "something"... Thanks!!

Please note that it is pseudo code, focus on the logic.

```
b_exception = false;
try{
   somethingThrowError();
}catch(Error e){
   b_exception =  true;
}
assertTrue(b_exception);
```

Comment: What is the unexpected thing?

Comment: I dont understand what you're asking...there is nothing wrong with the psudo code? are you saying that b_exception is false all the time?

Comment: With the code you've written, your boolean is set to false, you try something that throws an exception (I assume), it's then caught which sets the boolean to true, finally your assert statement checks it's true and execution will continue past this block. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Is `b_exception` a local variable or could it `somethingThrowError` set it to true without throwing an error?  Why `Error` and not `Throwable`?  Do you want the assertion to pass or fail if `somethingThrowError` throws an `Exception` instead of an `Error`?

Comment: Someone ask me about this question, that's all that I have, and he said there is a mistake, but I don't see anything wrong with its logic... So... anyone has any idea? Remember, it is just pseudo code, and there is one thing wrong in it's logic... that's the only hit that I've got. Please let me know if you know the answer. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what the problem is with your code because you haven't stated how it fails to fulfill your expectations, but the correct idiom for testing that an exception is thrown is to use JUnit 4's annotations:

```
@Test(expected=SpecificError.class)
public void testError(){
   somethingThrowError();
}
```

Comment: It is just pseudo code and my friend told me there is something wrong, like a testing question... but i really couldn't find any logic fault of that piece code. So... please let me know if you know what's wrong with the code, in the logic perspective. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I can only guess that you are looking for this:

```
try{
  somethingThrowError();
  fail("Exception expected");
}catch(AsSpecificAsPossibleException e){
  //should happen, OK
  //optionally assert exception message, etc.
}
```

Also note that catching an `Error` is a bad idea, use as specific exception as you can.

UPDATE: *@Michael Borgwardt's* answer is actually even better, but only if there is nothing except a single line in your test (nothing else that can throw). Also `@Test(expected` does not allow you to perform extra exception message assertions (but should you?)

Comment: In fact it is so bad an idea that this code is broken, since fail() also just throws an AssertionError...

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt: Wow, good catch, corrected, thanks! I don't remember when was the last time I used `Error` explicitly...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you think is wrong with that code.
The `assertTrue` will always be executed, as will the `System.out.println`.
It - the `assertTrue` - will signal an error if the argument is not `true`, or "pass the test" if the argument is `true`.
Maybe you should use `System.out.println("b_exception = " + b_exception);` to see what is happening.